# Gensim Word2vec model parameter tuning

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am working on Word2Vec model. Is there any way to get the ideal value for one of its parameter i.e `iter`. Like the way we used do in K-Means (Elbo curve plot) to get the K value.Or is there any other way for parameter tuning on this model.

Answer (score 7):

There's no one ideal set of parameters for a word2vec session – it depends on your intended usage of the word-vectors.

For example, some research has suggested that using a larger `window` tends to position the final vectors in a way that's more sensitive to topical/domain similarity, while a smaller `window` value shifts the word-neighborhoods to be more syntactic/functional drop-in replacements for each other. So depending on *your* particular project goals, you'd want a different value here.

(Similarly, because the original word2vec paper evaluated models, & tuned model meta-parameters, based on the usefulness of the word-vectors to solve a set of English-language analogy problems, many have often tuned their models to do well on the same analogy task. But I've seen cases where the model that scores best on those analogies does worse when contributing to downstream classification tasks.)

So what you really want is a project-specific way to score a set of word-vectors, well-matched to your goals. Then, you run many alternate word2vec training sessions, and pick the parameters that do best on your score.

The case of `iter`/`epochs` is special, in that by the logic of the underlying stochastic-gradient-descent optimization method, you'd ideally want to use as many training-epochs as necessary for the per-epoch running 'loss' to stop improving. At that point, the model is plausibly as good as it can be – 'converged' – given its inherent number of free-parameters and structure. (Any further internal adjustments that improve it for some examples worsen it for others, and vice-versa.)

So potentially, you'd watch this 'loss', and choose a number of training-iterations that's just enough to show the 'loss' stagnating (jittering up-and-down in a tight window) for a few passes. However, the loss-reporting in gensim isn't yet quite optimal – see project bug #2617 – and many word2vec implementations, including gensim and going back to the original `word2vec.c` code released by Google researchers, just let you set a fixed count of training iterations, rather than implement any loss-sensitive stopping rules.